# How to test a CONSTRAINT in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have the following constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Movie
  ADD CONSTRAINT NomsRANGE
CHECK (totalNoms BETWEEN 0 AND 20);
```

...and used the following to try and test it:

```
INSERT INTO Movie
  (totalNoms)
VALUES
  ('23');
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot insert NULL into ("ALI"."MOVIE"."MOVIEID")
```

My scheme is:

```
Actor (actorID, lastName, firstName, middleName, suffix, gender, birthDate, deathDate)
Movie (movieID, title, year, company, totalNoms, awardsWon, DVDPrice, discountPrice)
Quote (quoteID, quote)
Role (roleID ,roleName ,gender ,actorID* ,movieID*) 
RoleQuote (roleID*, quoteID*)
```

And my relationships are:

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME                C                                                
------------------------------ -                                                
QUOTE_FK                       R                                                
ROLE_FK                        R                                                
MOVIE_ROLE_FK                  R                                                
ACTOR_ROLE_FK                  R                                                
ACTORID                        P                                                
MOVIEID                        P                                                
QUOTEID                        P                                                
ROLEID                         P                                                
ROLEQUOTEID                    P                                                

9 rows selected.

Answer:
```

The answer was simple none of you spotted this it took me all day but i solved it so am posting solution so it helps others.

INSERT INTO Movie(movieID, totalNoms)
VALUES('049', '22');

I missed the first value which was the primary key as the error was saying:
`cannot insert NULL into ("ALI"."MOVIE"."MOVIEID")`

When i entered a new primary key it showed the constraint was violated

Thank you guys for all the help

Comment: And the problem is..? `Movieid` is initialised as `not null` right?

Comment: @user1137472 - I don't understand your update, both OMG Ponies and Justin Cave told you that you had to supply a value for `movieid`. You also don't need quotes around the values if they are `number` columns.

Comment: Your test should test only one very specific thing. Are you testing whether a text value such as `'23'` can is coerced into a (invalid) numeric value? That Oracle itself does not have any bugs that prevent a very trivial constraint from working? That the table does not have triggers that will bite before the `CHECK` does? At face value, your test doesn't seem to amount to much. Perhaps you should instead consider whether the code correctly implements the spec e.g. when the designer said, "...values up to 20" did they intend for 20 to be valid? What about nulls and other edge cases? etc

Comment: Some light reading over lunch, I just read this: "'We're on 15th. So we've got to sit through 15 numbers, then we're on." ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you omit columns in an INSERT statement, the database still needs to fill the column for that row.  Which would be `NULL`, unless you setup a DEFAULT constraint/etc for each column.

The error is telling you that `MOVIE.movieid` does not accept `NULL`, which is good.  It sounds like you need to setup the sequence to populate the value, or provide logic for however you want `MOVIE.movieid` populated (far less ideal).  The sequence can either be referenced in the INSERT statement to fill the value, or you can look at triggers/default constraints to handle things in the background.

You'll have to figure out how you want/need to handle any other errors relating to column NULLability.  Only after this is done, will you be able to see if your CHECK constraint works -- there's a little concern about if the value is provided as a string, if Oracle will implicitly convert it to an INT/NUMERIC data type.

Answer (score 3):

1) The specific error is telling you that your `INSERT` statement needs to specify the `MovieID`.  If you have created sequences to generate your synthetic primary key values, you'd want something like this (assuming there are no other NOT NULL columns in the `Movie` table)

```
INSERT INTO Movie
  (movieID, totalNoms)
VALUES
  (movieId_seq.nextval, 23);
```

2) Assuming that `totalNoms` is a `NUMBER` since your check constraint is treating it like a number, you would want to insert the number 23 rather than the string `23`.  Forcing Oracle to do implicit conversions is never a good idea-- it probably won't matter on a simple `INSERT` like this but if you get in the habit of using numbers when you're dealing with numeric fields and strings when you're dealing with character fields, life will be a lot easier.

Comment: ok but one question what is _seq? i dont understand this concept?

Comment: That does not work it says sequence does not exist of course it doesn't exist am trying to test the constraint not add a value.

Comment: @user1137472 - You can't test the constraint without inserting a new row (or at least trying to insert a new row).  How do you determine the next `MovieID` to use on an insert?  Most people would create a sequence (I guessed at the name, perhaps you used a different name) to generate values and use that sequence in each `INSERT`.

Comment: It still says sequence does not exist

Comment: @user1137472 - How do you determine the next 'MovieID` to use on an insert?  Did you create a sequence with a different name?

Comment: To add new record i use the following:


INSERT INTO Movie VALUES ('025', 'Midnight Cowboys', '1969', 'Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer', '5', '2', '17.99', '11.99');

Comment: @user1137472 unless you are you using some sort of natural key for your primary keys, you should have a sequence defined. Oracle has no auto-increment functionality like some rdbms'; you need to use a sequence for that. Here is a link to the Oracle 10g docs where they tell you how to create a sequence: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm